# Spare tire different than on-road tires

Tags: tires

Replaced 4 225 75r16's on my 2007 E150 with 245 75r16's, but not the spare, it remains a
225 75r16.  Can I use this in an emergency situation?

Answer (score 0):

Tire size calculators are extremely helpful tools.  https://tiresize.com/calculator/ is just one of the many sites.  Putting your two sizes in I see they are 27 revolutions/mile different.  There 2 scenarios that each take their own special rules.

##### Flat on Drive Axle

If your axle is an open differential it will handle this, but if it's a limited slip diff then swap a good tire from the other axle and put the different sized spare on that axle.

*For example, on a rear wheel drive with a limited slip diff, the spare would go up front.*

##### Flat on Non Drive Axle

Doesn't matter too much, just might handle a bit odd especially if it's up front.  You also might notice some pulling to the shorter tire, but with modern cars and power steering you probably won't feel much different.